# The section is not for generic purpose

Tags: html

I am trying to understand the purpose of the section and found the following article:

> The section element is not a generic container element. Now I know
>   what it says. It says above that it represents a generic section of a
>   document. When people write specifications, sometimes they get vague.
>   It is not a generic container.
>
> When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a
>   convenience for scripting, things like JavaScript, authors are
>   encouraged to use the div element, which we'll talk about in just a
>   little bit. So a general rule is that the section element is
>   appropriate only if the elements contents would be listed explicitly
>   in the documents outline and that's where it reaches the sweet spot.
>   When you have content that needs to be listed in the document outline
>   but it doesn't meet the standard of being syndicated or pushed apart
>   by itself, then that's when the section element is probably
>   appropriate.

The questions are:

- What is a generic container?
- What does he mean with *styling purposes
  or as a convenience for scripting*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is a generic container?

An element that can be used as a containing element for any arbitrary content, in any arbitrary context. E.g. `div` is the most generic container there is, because it does not carry any meaning in itself whatsoever. `section` *does* have a specific meaning, so shouldn't be used arbitrarily.

> What does he mean with *styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting*?

When you want to style specific elements or you want to programmatically access specific elements via Javascript, you need some *hook* for that element. E.g., styling the eighteenth word in this sentence is pretty difficult, but becomes much easier when you <span>wrap</span> it in something. Now you can use `span { color: red }` or `document.getElementsByTagName('span')` to do something with that element.